# How to compare single values of a vector with matrix and if they occur take values from another matrix with the same position?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I'm a programming beginner and I'm not able to solve this problem:

I have a vector length 132 and two matrices A and B with the size of 132x24. I would like to take every single value of the vector and compare it rowwise with matrix A. If the value occurs in A I want to have the index of the column to go to matrix B and pick the value from the column with the same position (row and column indices) as in matrix A. The results should be given back as a vector with the same length of 132.

How to do this? Do I need a for loop or are there some smart ways to work with packages?

Unfortunately I can not give example data.

Thank you for your help!

```
# vector v contains values that I want to compare with matrix A
> v
[1]  5  1 10  1  7

# every single value of v occurs in every row of A only once
# I want to have the position of this value in matrix A
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    7    4    1
[2,]   14    1    3    3
[3,]   13    3    1   10
[4,]    2    1    5    8
[5,]   13    2    5    7

# the position in matrix A equals the position in matrix B
# now the values of B have to be returned as a vector 
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    3    4    3
[2,]    5    2    5    5
[3,]    4    6    3    1
[4,]    3    6    1    5
[5,]    2    4    6    3

# vector with fitting values of B
> x
[1] 6 2 1 6 3
```

Comment: 132 cols, 24 rows?

Comment: no, 132x24 so 132 rows and 24 cols

Comment: It needs to be said explicitly, there is no rule either way. And even if there was, it is always better to be clear. Since you refuse to give sample data and expect us to figure out, we don't want to waste time in the wrong direction

Comment: And what is "compare rowwise"? Without sample data and desired output, you keep us guessing.

Comment: why cant you share sample data and expected output?

Comment: ok give me a minute

Comment: What if a value occurs multiple times in one row of A?

Comment: the values occur only once in every row

Comment: Well, that information would have been useful an hour ago...

Answer (score 2):

```
v <- c(5,  1, 10,  1,  7)
A <- matrix(c(
   5,    7,    4,    1,    
  14,    1,    3,    3,
  13,    3,    1,   10,    
   2,    1,    5,    8,   
  13,    2,    5,    7), 5, byrow = TRUE)
B <- matrix(c(
6,    3,    4,    3,
5,    2,    5,    5,
4,    6,    3,    1,
3,    6,    1,    5,
2,    4,    6,    3), 5, byrow = TRUE)

myfun <- function(i) which(v[i]==A[i,])  

ii <- 1:length(v)
B[cbind(ii, sapply(ii, myfun))]
```

The function `myfun()` is quick'n'dirty.
To test if your data are ok you can calculate how often the value `v[i]` is found in the row `A[i,]`

```
countv <- function(i) sum(v[i]==A[i,])
all(sapply(ii, countv)==1) ### should be TRUE
```

If you get `FALSE` then inspect:

```
which(sapply(ii, countv)!=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works fine. Unfortunately it doesn't work for my data. I get: invalid subscript type 'list'... As I said I'm a beginner and it's difficult to understand

Comment: Inspect the result of `sapply(ii, myfun)` of eventually `sapply(sapply(ii, myfun), length)`. Eventally the assertion ***"the values occur only once in every row"*** is wrong for your data. Is it possible that the value `v[i]` can not be fount in the row `A[i,]` ?

Comment: so I checked the data and indeed there was one mistake. now everything works great. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'm not sure how you pictured your output, but I've got something that comes near.

Example data:

```
x <- 1:132
set.seed(123)
A <- matrix(sample(1:1000, size = 132*24, replace = TRUE), nrow = 132, ncol = 24)
B <- matrix(rnorm(132*24), nrow = 132, ncol = 24)
```

Now we check for every value of vector `x` if and where it occurs in every row of matrix `A`:

```
x.vs.A <- sapply(x, function(x){
  apply(A, 1, function(y) {
    match(x, y)
  })
})
```

This gives us a matrix `x.vs.A` with 132 rows (the rows of `A`) and 132 columns (the values of `x`). Within the cells of this matrix, we will find either `NA`, if the combination of one value of `x` and one row of `A` was unsuccessful, or the column position within `A` of the **FIRST** match of the value of `x`.

And now we extract the rowwise position and bind them together with the cell value, depiting the second (column) dimension of the matched value. Thus we create for every value of `x` a matrix of row/column position of matches in matrix `A`:

```
x.in.A <- apply(x.vs.A, 2, function(x) cbind(which(!is.na(x)), x[!is.na(x)]))
```

Example:

```
> x.in.A[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   12   17
[2,]   42   17
[3,]   73   12
[4,]  123   21
```

This would show that the first value in vector `x` can be found in `A[12, 17]`, in `A[42, 17]` and so on.

Now access these values in `B`, returning vectors for each value of `x`, and bind them to the matrices in the list:

```
x.in.B <- lapply(x.in.A, function(x){
  apply(x, 1, function(y){
    B[y[1], y[2]]
  })
})

x.in.AB <- mapply(function(x, y) cbind(x, y),
                  x.in.A, x.in.B)

> x.in.AB[[1]]
                     y
[1,]  12 17 -0.2492526
[2,]  42 17 -0.7985330
[3,]  73 12  0.1253824
[4,] 123 21 -0.9704919
```